# Можно ли узнать, существует ли еще "первый" умный указатель?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointer

```
std::map <int, std::shared_ptr<A>> m;
std::shared_ptr<A> *a = &m[2];
std::shared_ptr<A> *b = &m[2];
m.erase(2);
if(a) std::cout << "exist a\n";
if(b) std::cout << "exist b\n";
```

Можно ли как-то узнать с минимальными издержками (элементов в карте много) существует ли m[2]? Возможно ли каким-то образом узнать это посредством а и b? Можно ли как-то при удалении m[2] обнулить/освободить корректно память, на которую они ссылаются и таким образом выполнить проверку?

Comment: Гм... Как-то меня напрягает использование *указателя* на `shared_ptr`... Не в смысле языковых возможностей, а в смысле дизайна, понятно...

Comment: @Harry А меня не напрягает. И проблемы дизайна будут решаться мной отдельно и не здесь. Если Вы думаете, что это весь код, то глубоко заблуждаетесь. Если же есть чего сказать/добавить по вопросу - милости просим. Даже можно и про дизайн, про то как Вы лично видите решение. Но не нужно писать про Ваше напряжение - это не интересно. А свое напряжение можете сбросить... минусованием вопроса.

Comment: Интересная у вас реакция... неадекватная какая-то. Про дизайн - можно. Если знать задачу. Просто сам `shared_ptr` для того и создан, чтобы избавиться от указателей. Кстати, предложенное вам решение их не использует! Поэтому указатель на `shared_ptr`... ладно, раз вы в бутылку и вам не понравилось мое вежливое замечание, так тому и быть, скажу прямо - решение глупое. И еще - не рассказывайте мне, что мне можно писать, а что нет, и я не буду рассказывать вам, куда пойти.         Ко всем читающим: простите великодушно, была бы здесь личка - написал бы там, а так вам приходится это читать... :(

Comment: @Harry А Вам не кажется, что именно Ваша реакция на сам мой вопрос была в корне не верна? Если Вы не знаете задачу, то как можно было писать про дизайн, а теперь оправдываться незнанием задачи? Вам не кажется, что данный ресурс преследует цель вопросов и ответов, а не описания своего напряжения на основании домыслов о дизайне? И не кажется ли Вам, что для того, чтобы не сожалеть об отсутствии лички, просто не надо изначально писать глупые комментарии, тогда и не придется потом просить прощения у остальных читающих?

Comment: @Harry Есть вполне четкие правила ресурса: есть что написать по поводу вопроса - так напиши. Считаешь вопрос не правильным - минусуй его и напиши в комментариях почему так считаешь. А писать свои домыслы лучше всего в своих блогах. Также можно еще сказать, что берите лушче пример с автора ответа - он ответил на вопрос и, косвенно, решил вопрос об указателях на shaed_ptr, тем самым "предложив" более правильный дизайн.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в `std::map` хранить `std::shared_ptr`, а для `a` и `b` использовать `std::weak_ptr`:

```
std::map <int, std::shared_ptr<A>> m;
std::weak_ptr<A> a = m[2];
std::weak_ptr<A> b = m[2];
m.erase(2);
if (!a.expired()) std::cout << "exist a\n";
if (!b.expired()) std::cout << "exist b\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно :) А то я как-то уперся в unique_ptr и shared_ptr и совсем не подумал (забыл) о weak_ptr.